# General rules of worshipping Lord Hanuman

Tags: worship, hanuman

What are the General rules of worshipping Lord Hanuman?

Comment: Narada Purana mentions general rules for worshiping Hanuman. But i'm not sure how those rules are relevant to this Kaliyuga.

Comment: Im not sure about the rules, but here is some food for thought. They say that Lord Hanuman loves Lord Rama and instantly manifests Himself when Lord Rama's name is chanted, for He Loves Lord Rama so much. So a wise way would be to add prayers to Lord Rama in addition to Lord Hanuman, thereby Lord Hanuman will be pleased with the devotion. Also when Lord Hanuman is pleased, Lord Rama too becomes ours! Such is the love between Bhakta and Bhagavan. All the best.

Comment: @TheDestroyer You must give the answer. It would be beneficial and knowledgeable